# returning boolean value in function

Tags: f#

I have this function:

```
let myFunction list (var1, var2) : bool =
    for (x,y) in list do
        match (var1, var2) with
        | (1, 11) | (2, 22) -> true
        | (_, _) ->
            if not (x = y) then
                true // error is here
            false
```

This returns an error saying that the function expects the value returned to have type bool, not unit. What I want to achieve is to return true whenever `x != y` so the loop should stop there; otherwise to return false at the end.

Comment: What exactly was the error message? I assume that the problem is that a simple if-expression without else cannot return any value (other than unit). The reason is that the function needs some return value and if there is no else-part, this is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 4):

In F#, if statements can return.  As a result, if you put the `true` on its own, you need to put a matching false so that both sides of the `if` return bool like so

```
        if not (x = y) then
            true 
        else false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop searching as soon as a match is found, try something like:

```
let myFunction list (var1, var2) : bool =
    match (var1, var2) with
    | (1, 11) | (2, 22) -> true
    | _ -> Seq.exists (fun (x, y) -> x <> y) list
```

`Seq.exists` takes a function returning a boolean and goes through the list until it finds an element for which the function returns `true`, in which case it will itself return `true`.  If it reaches the end of the list without finding any such elements, it will return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

First, "if x then true else false" is the same as "x".

So this (you forgot the else-part as John pointed out):

```
if not (x = y) then
   true
else false
```

can be simplified to:

```
x <> y
```

Your function is a bit weird though. I think this might be what you mean:

```
let myFunction list (var1, var2) =
    List.exists (fun (x, y) -> match (var1, var2) with
                               | (1, 11) | (2, 22) -> true
                               | _ -> (x <> y))
                list
```

The check of var1 and var2 can be moved out of List.exists. So:

```
let myFunction list = function
                      | (1, 11) | (2, 22) -> true
                      | _ -> List.exists (fun (x, y) -> x <> y) list
```